# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQsetErrorContextVisibility

Tags: macos, homebrew, psql

On running

```
$ psql
```

I get this error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
_PQsetErrorContextVisibility
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _PQsetErrorContextVisibility
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

I have tried a few things:

1. few posts suggested to update brew
2. few suggested adding /usr/local/bin/psql to the ~/.bash_profile and restarting the system
3. few said it was problem with XCode but I do not have XCode installed so it isnt valid for me I guess.

but none of it worked.

my bash_profile looks like this

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin/psql:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin
:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin/geckodrive‌​r:$PATH"
export PATH
```

I am using:

- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2
- macOS Sierra version 10.12.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was on PostgreSQL 9.6.2 as well,
and ran into the same problem.

I upgraded to 9.6.3 using brew like this:

```
rm '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib'
brew upgrade postgresql
brew link postgresql
```

It worked, and now I have access via psql again.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try it once I get my machine back and accept the answer once it works.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that worked for me was uninstalling and reinstalling postgres using the code below:

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql
```