# psql error dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql

When I try to connect PostgreSQL locally by running as below,

```
$ /usr/local/pg10.11/bin/psql
```

Throghing below error,

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQsetErrorContextVisibility
  Referenced from: /usr/local/pg10.11/bin/psql
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _PQsetErrorContextVisibility
  Referenced from: /usr/local/pg10.11/bin/psql
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

This is started when I was upgraded PostgreSQL v10.11 to v11, before that it worked fine.
even I tried steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393800/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-pqseterrorcontextvisibility/44468227#44468227) but no luck.

Please help me here and appreciated the response.

Note: I didn't install PostgreSQL through brew, installed from source code.

Enviranment:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.11 
macOS Catalina version 10.15.1
```